# Paypal javascript sdk - shipping address

Tags: javascript, paypal, sdk, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I am trying to implement express checkout button with javascript sdk. Also sending the shipping address along with it. but when i login to the paypal account for payment, its not taking the shipping address which i am sending. its taking the one alredy from the account. How can i configure so that it will take my provided shipping address? moreover, it should be validated as well??

hier is the sample code i am using

```
 createOrder: function(data, actions) {
             return actions.order.create({
                 purchase_units: [{
                     amount: {
                         value: valueTotal,
                         currency_code: currencyCode,
                         breakdown: {
                             item_total: {
                                 currency_code: currencyCode,
                                 value: valueTotal
                             },
                             shipping: {
                                 currency_code: currencyCode,
                                 value: "0"
                             },
                         }
                     },
                     item_number: skuNum,
                     item_name: itemName,

                     items: [{
                         name: itemName,
                         unit_amount: {value: valueTotal, currency_code: currencyCode},
                         quantity: '1',
                         sku: skuNum
                     }],
                     shipping: {
                         name: {
                             full_name: fullName,
                         },
                         address: {

                             address_line_1: company,
                             address_line_2: street + houseNo,
                             admin_area_2: city,
                             admin_area_1: state,
                             postal_code: zip,
                             country_code: countryCode
                         },
                     }
                 }],
                 application_context: {
                     shipping_preference: 'SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS',
                 }
             });
         },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i know the problem why paypal was rejecting my given shipping address. in address line 1 i had company, which is optional field. if that is blank, paypal ignores complete shipping address and takes from the account.